# Send invoices with paypal api?

Tags: paypal

I want to allow users to be able to send a paypal invoice in 1-click to their client.
angelleye gave me his php CreateAndSendInvoice.php file that is supposed to do that, but how do I start using it, do I need an api key?

The key is each user would have to enter some sort of credentials to verify my app to be able to send out invoices on their behalf.

Does anyone know how to do this? (website is https://cworklog.com )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, I would recommend avoiding the actual invoicing API for now.  I've been using it with a client of mine and it's very buggy right now.

If you pass your own invoice ID into CreateInvoice or CreateAndSendInvoice it will only sometimes be returned via IPN.  PayPal can't seem to tell me why this is.

Also, if you need to re-send invoices it can be a pain.  SendInvoice only works once.  You will get an error if you try to use that to send the same invoice again.  Your only option at that point is to use the InvoiceURL returned when you first create the invoice.

This would be fine except that when this URL is used it forces a login to PayPal to view the invoice so guest checkout (paying with a credit card instead of a PayPal account) cannot be used this way.

Also, GetTransactionDetails is not returning the invoice ID for PayPal invoices either.  I tried to use it as a work-around to the IPN issue and was shut down on that idea.

I would honestly recommend you just setup your own invoicing system.  It really wouldn't be that much more work than building actual invoicing API requests.

You could let your users setup their invoice items and basically create an invoice in your own database.  Then generate a basic HTML email with a pay button that points to a URL on your server.  This URL can pull all of the order details back out to display an invoice to the payer on screen.

You can build Express Checkout into this for the payment processing and all of the issues I mentioned above wouldn't get in your way.

You can use the Permissions API to allow users to grant permission for your app to make calls on their behalf.  Users could also do this manually through their PayPal account profile under "Request API Credentials."  Instead of creating their own they would choose to Grant API Permissions and then enter your API username along with checking boxes for the permissions they'd like to approve.

Answer Summary:

- Setup your API calls on the sandbox so you have a working demo.
- Submit your application to x.com for approval.  This will get you a live App ID to use against the live PayPal servers.
- Have your users grant permissions to your app manually from within their PayPal account or via the API using the Permissions API.
- Build your system to use the tokens obtained via Permissions API for your customers accordingly.

Comment: I already set up my own invoicing system but because some clients like to be invoiced they ask "Please send me a paypal invoice." Instead of going to paypal and logging in with username and password and going through the process of creating an invoice, it would be much easier to do it from my app

Comment: Yeah, if they specifically ask for it I guess that's an issue.  Just keep in mind you're going to run into all of these same issues I mentioned that I'm running into.  That is unless I can get them to fix some of them along the way here.

Comment: Also, the answer about the Permissions API still stands.  You can use that to let people approve your app to make calls on their behalf.  I updated the answer to be more specific for you.